# Changed naming convention for .data() keys

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, widget, jquery-migrate

Previously for custom widgets I used code like this:

```
var bar = $( "<div />")
    .appendTo( "body" )
    .progressbar()
    .data( "progressbar" );
```

but with jQuery UI 1.10 this code doesn't work any more... data("progressbar") doesn't return anything.

I tested it with the widget example from http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/stateful-plugins-with-widget-factory/ where the widget has name with namespace "nmk.progressbar"

In the upgrade guide from jQuery 1.9 to 1.10 I found this: http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#changed-naming-convention-for-data-keys but still have no idea what I should change in order get it working back...

Comment: I tried this already and it didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a prefix `ui-` to the previous key like `ui-progressbar`.

From [Doc](http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#changed-naming-convention-for-data-keys)

> Widget instances now use the full name, including the namespace, e.g.,
>   ui-dialog instead of dialog

Use

```
var bar = $( "<div />")
    .appendTo( "body" )
    .progressbar()
    .data( "ui-progressbar" );
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SbWqY/)

Comment: I tried that one already and it doesn't work... if I try to use  .data("ui-progressbar") it still returns nothing for me

Comment: @AlexWheat look at the attached fiddle... it is working... if it is not working in your site there there is some other problem...

Comment: @AlexWheat try `.data()` and see what are the data keys available as shown in the fiddle

Comment: don't know why yet but for me my example works only when I use .data( "nmk-progressbar" ); and doesn't work with "ui-progressbar". I see only one difference here - I'm currently using jQuery UI 1.10.0 but fiddle using 1.10.3. Will try to upgrade mine tile the 1.10.3

Comment: @AlexWheat I don't think that is the problem... what is the jQuery version used?

Comment: @AlexWheat are you using  a custom progress bar widget... can you look at the widget definition is the widget name specified as `ui.progressbar` or `nmk.progressbar`...

Comment: another possibility is that there is another progressbar plugin in the page

Comment: Yes, the widget's name specified as 'nmk.progressbar'... here is the demo widget that I'm working with http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/stateful-plugins-with-widget-factory/

Comment: and there is no any other progressbar plugin on the page... Ok, Arun, I think I figured out what is the problem now and how to deal with that! thanks for your prompt answers and navigating me to the right direction.